# generic protocol that has a variable of type generic protocol

Tags: swift, generics, interface, protocols

How can I create a generic protocol, that has a type of another generic protocol?

In my example I have a Heap, which is a Protocol of a generic type, since I can have any elements in my heap, which conform to Comparable protocol.

So in my priorityQueue, which I also want to make as a protocol (in order to avoid code duplication and to practice) I want my priorityQueue to contain a heap where Heap.T is equal to PriorityQueue.Item, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Of course I could do it with "abstract classes", but it's not the point here.

BTW the code below even doesn't compile

Code:

```
public protocol PriorityQueuable: Hashable {
    associatedtype KeyType: Comparable
    associatedtype ValueType: Comparable

    var key: KeyType { get set }
    var value: ValueType { get set }
}

protocol Heap {
    associatedtype T: Comparable

    var data: [T] { get set }

    mutating func heapify(parentIndex: Int)
}

protocol PriorityQueue {
    associatedtype Item: PriorityQueuable

    //FIXME: doesn't allow me to do that. Why?
    var heap: Heap<Item> { get set }

    // doesn't compile as well 
    // var heap: Heap { get set }   
}
```

Comment: What if you make `PriorityQueue` a subclass of `Heap`?

Comment: Since data structures in Swift are mostly Structs, I wanted to make a concrete implementation of a priority queue as a struct. But since structs are not allowed to be inherited, then I decided to not consider this option.
+ it's a new opportunity to learn something about the language

Comment: Try wrapping `Heap` with a generic class

Comment: @paper1111 is there another way of doing that?

Comment: @denis631 Do you mean wrapping `Heap` or what?

Comment: @paper1111 i wanted to write that `var heap: Heap<T> where T = Item { get set }`

Comment: `Item` is not comparable so of course you can't pass it into the protocol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149318/discussion-between-denis631-and-paper1111).

Comment: @paper1111 it doesn't work even when PriorityQueable is expects it to be Hashable & Comparable. I've tested it

Answer (score 2):

This code works:

```
public protocol PriorityQueuable: Hashable {
    associatedtype KeyType: Comparable
    associatedtype ValueType: Comparable

    var key: KeyType { get set }
    var value: ValueType { get set }
}

protocol Heap {
    associatedtype T: Comparable

    var data: [T] { get set }

    mutating func heapify(parentIndex: Int)
}

class AnyHeap<U: Comparable>: Heap {
    public init(data: [U], heapify: @escaping (_ parentIndex: Int) -> ()) {
        self.data = data
        self.anyHeapify = heapify
    }

    var anyHeapify: (_ parentIndex: Int) -> ()
    var data: [U]
    func heapify(parentIndex: Int) {
        self.anyHeapify(parentIndex)
    }
}

protocol PriorityQueue {
    associatedtype Item: PriorityQueuable, Comparable

    var heap: AnyHeap<Item> { get set }   
}
```

Note that there is an additional `AnyHeap` class which conforms to `Heap`. `AnyHeap` **is** a `Heap` due to polymorphism. (Note that `Item` has to conform to `Comparable` to conform to protocol `Heap)` Implementing those protocols is extremely easy:

```
class AQueueable: PriorityQueuable, Comparable {
    var hashValue: Int { return 1 }
    var key: String = "Hi"
    var value: String = "YoMaMa"
    static func < (lhs: AQueueable, rhs: AQueueable) -> Bool {
        // implement code
        return false
    }
    static func == (lhs: AQueueable, rhs: AQueueable) -> Bool {
        // implement code
        return false
    }
}

class AQueue: PriorityQueue {
    var heap: AnyHeap = AnyHeap<AQueueable>(data: [AQueueable](), heapify: { parentIndex in
        // implement code
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks, but that was exactly the thing which I was trying to avoid, namely, creating a generic class. I wanted to solve it only using generic protocols. Seems, that Swift doesn't allow it right now

Comment: Since even apple has AnyDictionaries and AnyArrays... Not very swifty and beautiful though ...

Comment: There's a great article here on why `AnyHashable` works so you can easily create your own boxed erasure types and avoid a lot of generics: https://kandelvijaya.com/2016/10/10/swift3-why-anyhashable-how-does-it-work-internally/